# AngularJS how to alert object value

Tags: angularjs

I want to alert an `object` value in AngularJs, how does one do that?

If I simply alert the object by `alert(obj)` then it shows the result as `object object` in alert box.

Comment: Try `alert(JSON.stringify(obj));`

Answer (score 8):

One way is

`alert(JSON.stringify(obj));` .

Comment: In fact most correct way in Angular would be to use `angular.toJson(obj)`

Answer (score 0):

If you do it for development purpose just to see object content, much better to use inspector in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox.

You can use `$log` service for that.

```
$log.info(obj);
```

This gives you advantage that you can now see object as tree and you can navigate. In alert some objects may be bigger that alert window.

Comment: i am using angularJS in phonegape, so how i see output using this?

Comment: Use Ripple chrome extension to emulate phonegap app in Chrome but like you run it on a device. And use standard chrome inspector then.

Answer (score 0):

One can log it to the console (in any browser's `F12` tools) such as

```
 console.log(obj);
```

or to json-ify it in the `alert` popup such as

```
alert(angular.toJson(obj));
```